# Compare XML ignoring specific XPaths

Tags: xml, xpath, xmlunit

I am using XML Unit to comparing two XMLs and check whether the two are similar.
My requirement is - I want to ignore specific XPATHs during the comparison.
How can I ignore the given XPATH from comparing as the XPATH can be any valid Xpath syntax ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I use xslt to remove elements by xpath and then compare two processed xml.

Answer (score 1):

You should use a `DifferenceListener` and implement the `differenceFound` method. 
The argument difference provides the location so you can use this information to compare with your XPath list to ignore.

```
difference.getTestNodeDetail().getXpathLocation()
```